# Increase the size of flex item on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

I want to add a feature such that when I click the `flex-item` it must expand to size of complete row below it. Like basically increase it's size when I click on it, and get back to previous size when I click it again.

The subsequent `elements` must remain of same size and be shifted to next row after the expanded clicked `flex-item` and follow the same properties of `flex-box`. The `flex-items` must be clickable `elements` which expand on click and get back to same size on another click.

I am not able to figure this out and I am new to front-end technologies.

```js
$('#clickMe').click(function() {
    $('#Demosss').append($('<li id="flx-item" class="flex-item">').text('dar'));
    $(this).insertAfter($('[class^="flex-item"]').last());
});
```

```css
.flex-container {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row; /* Safari */
    flex-direction:  row;
    flex-wrap:  wrap;
}
.flex-item {
    background: tomato;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    line-height: 150px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    
}
ul li{
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="Demosss" class="flex-container">
<!-- add LI here -->
</ul>


<button id="clickMe">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `toggle` class on click.

```js
var i = 1; // just for differentiate divs
$('#clickMe').click(function() {
    $('#Demosss').append($('<li id="flx-item" class="flex-item">').text('dar-'+i));
    $(this).insertAfter($('[class^="flex-item"]').last());
    i++
});

$(document).on('click', '.flex-item' ,function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('flexActive')
})
```

```css
.flex-container {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row; /* Safari */
    flex-direction:  row;
    flex-wrap:  wrap;
}
.flex-item {
    background: tomato;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    line-height: 150px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    
}
ul li{
  display: inline;
}
.flexActive{
  width:auto;
  display:block;
  flex: 1 1;
  margin-right:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="Demosss" class="flex-container">
<!-- add LI here -->
</ul>


<button id="clickMe">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to just add a class to the clicked flex-item that sets its width to 100%, then toggle this class on click.

Now I don't know if you wanted to: (a) just expand one flex-item at a time; or (b) you'd want to retract flex items on click only, but I made scenario (a) in my answer as this probably makes more sense. Nevertheless, you can go for scenario (b) by deleting this line of code:

> $('.expand').removeClass('expand');

```js
$('#clickMe').click(function() {
            $('#Demosss').append($('<li id="flx-item" class="flex-item">').text('dar'));
            $(this).insertAfter($('[class^="flex-item"]').last());
        });
    $(document).on('click','.flex-item',function(){
      $('.expand').removeClass('expand');
      $(this).toggleClass('expand');
       
    });
```

```css
.flex-container {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row; /* Safari */
    flex-direction:  row;
    flex-wrap:  wrap;
}
.flex-item {
    background: tomato;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    line-height: 150px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    
}
ul li{
  display: inline;
}
.expand {
width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="Demosss" class="flex-container">
<!-- add LI here -->
</ul>


<button id="clickMe">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: `$(this).toggleClass('expand');` does not make any sense if you are already removing `expand` class with `$('.expand').removeClass('expand');`, at least check your answer before posting.

Comment: I'm afraid you are wrong @TalentRunners. Have you tried removing it then seeing the effect? If you remove that line of code, you can have more than one flex item expanded at the same time. Having this code allows you to only have one flex-item expanded at a time.  That said, my answer allows for this flexibility since the OP didn't specify which scenario s/he wanted.